# How to recover account

Tags: support

I have not used this site in years. When I tried to ask a question it says "we are not accepting questions from this account.

How to recover account? Or do I simply have to use another account to ask questions?

Comment: You are asking about your SU account, right?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Use another account, you are question banned. Final solution. Make sure to use new ip and email so they don't catch you. And leave at least 1 to 2 days in between logins to new and old account.

Answer (score 5):

Well, your account is working as designed - you, however have been question banned.

While link only answers are frowned on - there's a meta.se post explaining [what to do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Using another account is probably not the best idea.

Comment: - Do you know if the 6 month rate limit also applies to answers as well?

Comment: That's literally the best information even us mods have, so no idea specifically

Comment: Well if the user is question banned then they will be allowed to ask a question after 6 months. If they are answer banned (which I thought they were asking about for some reason) I am not sure if the rate limit applies.

Comment: @Ramhound No rate limit for answer bans. See https://superuser.com/help/answer-bans "Stack Exchange cannot lift answer bans by request.

The only way to end a posting block is to positively contribute to the site; automatic bans never expire or "time out". "

Comment: @DavidPostill - The problem is that, same answer indicates a 6-month rate limit, on submitting questions

Comment: @Ramhound Yes. There is a rate limit for questions. But not for answers.

Comment: @DavidPostill - I figured I knew the answer, but "question bans" have also morphed into "question rate limits" over the years.  So I wasn't sure if the rate limit applied to answers or not.